# Force VS Code devcontainer settings to override user settings

Tags: laravel, docker, visual-studio-code, laravel-sail, vscode-devcontainer

My team is beginning a new project (using Laravel, if that makes a difference) & we'd like to share the same environments where ever possible. This includes VS Code configuration for extensions & settings. So we're going forward with using VS Code devcontainers alongside Laravel Sail (Docker). I was able to successfully open the project in a devcontainer using the `devcontainer.json` file, including adding extensions. However, the container is not overriding settings that have already been set in a users `settings.json` file. For example:

**User settings.json file**

```
{
    "files.eol": "\n"
}
```

**devcontainer.json file**

```
"customizations": {
    "vscode": {
        "settings": {
            "files.eol": "\r\n"
        }
    }
}
```

When considering the above two files, if I reopen the project using the `Reopen in Container` command provided by VS Code, the `devcontainer.json` settings will not be used; it will still use the users `settings.json` file.

So my question is: can I force VS Code to use the settings provided in the `devcontainer.json` file, superseding all others?

Here is my full `devcontainer.json` file.

```
// https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json
{
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense",
                "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client",
                "neilbrayfield.php-docblocker",
                "rexshi.phpdoc-comment-vscode-plugin",
                "MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver",
                "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker",
                "emeraldwalk.RunOnSave",
                "mhutchie.git-graph",
                "waderyan.gitblame",
                "christian-kohler.path-intellisense"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "files.eol": "\r\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml"],
    "name": "project-name",
    "postCreateCommand": "chown -R 1000:1000 /var/www/html",
    "remoteUser": "sail",
    "service": "main",
    "workspaceFolder": "/var/www/html"
}
```

I've tried

- Formatting the `settings` key in the devcontainer file differently.
- Running the container first (via Laravel Sail) then connecting VS Code to the already running container
- Running the container & opening it in VS Code via the `Reopen in Container` command provided by VS Code

Comment: I'm using cookiecutter django's bootstrapped devcontainer.json, and none of those settings are being applied in my dev container either; interestingly, if I run `docker inspect <name_of_dev_container>`, all the devcontainer settings are present as labels...